# Using relational operators in C++

Tags: c++

am just learning C++ programming and my problem is that am trying to compare more than one variables and is not working. This is what I typed : `if ( a > b > c)`.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't work like this, as the first expression `a > b` evaluates to a boolean, which is converted (because of the comparison with `c`) to either `0` or `1`, depending on its truth value. You then attempt to compare it with `c`, which is not what you want. Use

```
if ( (a > b) && (b > c) )
```

instead. This way you compute the logical `AND` of two booleans, and if both are `true`, then the mathematical statement `a > b > c` is true (by transitivity).

If you compile with all warnings on, the compiler will (probably) warn you. At least g++ is saying:

> warning: comparisons like 'X<=Y<=Z' do not have their mathematical meaning [-Wparentheses]

Answer (score 3):

You have to seperate both conditions via **AND(&&)** Operator

```
if ( (a>b) && (b > c) ){
   //code
}
```

Comment: The brackets aren't required here, as the answer suggests. That's not to say leaving them in is a bad idea.

Comment: I mean to say, you have to separate both condition check via AND or OR

Comment: @chris it's definitely better as otherwise most of us have to take a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Comment: thanks, it worked but i did it like this ; if (a > b && c) cout << " a is greater ";

Comment: @MichealObiora thats wrong because c will always be true unless its zero

Comment: @Nakib take note of the english comment ; if A is greater than B and also greater than C, then prints A is greater.